# combine jquery functions which have same code

Tags: jquery

I have the following finctions in my script and they do the same thing. How may I combine them?

```
$('.AddOne').live('click', function(){
    $('.saveGroup').show();
});
$('#PhoneNumbersSelectms2side__sx  option').dblclick(function(){
    $('.saveGroup').show();
});
$('.AddAll').live('click', function(){
    $('.saveGroup').show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `click` and `dblclick` event methods each take a callback function as their first argument. In javascript functions are variables. you create a function, and pass it to the callbacks

```
var showFn = function(){
    $('.saveGroup').show();
};

$('.AddOne').live('click', showFn);
$('#PhoneNumbersSelectms2side__sx  option').dblclick(showFn);
$('.AddAll').live('click', showFn);
```

You can further simplify this code by combining the live selectors like this:

```
$('.AddOne, .AddAll').live('click', showFn);
```

Finally, if you are using jquery 1.7.x you should use the new [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event methods instead of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Your new code would look like this:

```
var showFn = function(){
    $('.saveGroup').show();
};
var $doc = $(document);
$doc.on('click', '.AddOne, .AddAll', showFn);
$doc.on('dblclick', '#PhoneNumbersSelectms2side__sx  option', showFn);
```